# SQL Join : how to show the first table data even the 2nd table condition false

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I want to keep show my first table data even the second table condition is false.

Table 1

```
---------------------------
  ID  | Name
---------------------------
  1   | Panda
  2   | Tiger
---------------------------
```

Table 2

```
---------------------------
  ID  | Date       | Weight
---------------------------
  1   | 2019-02-01 |   30
  1   | 2019-02-10 |   31
---------------------------
```

I expect data like this when I asking data for the date = '2019-02-18' and ID = 1

```
-------------------------------------
  ID  | Name  | Date       |  Weight
-------------------------------------
  1   | Panda | 2019-02-18 |    0
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a simple `LEFT JOIN`, as follows ?

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, date '2019-02-18', COALESCE(t2.weight, 0) weight
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.date = date '2019-02-18'
WHERE t1.id = 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN` optionaly searches for record in `table2` with the given date criteria. When no record match, `t2.weight` is `NULL` : `COALESCE()` picks up this situation, and returns `0` instead.

Comment: `AND t2.date = date '2019-02-18'` are you sure?

Comment: thank you @GMB now I get what I want, I make a mistake when I put the date condition like this :
WHERE t1.id = 1 AND t2.date = date '2019-02-18'

Comment: @FerryFernandez : yes, you need the condition in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`, not in the `WHERE` clause, otherwise it becomes similar to an `INNER JOIN`